# Rsync via SSH doesn't work

Tags: ssh, nas, rsync, centos-6

I want to make a backup from a Synology DiskStation (DSM 6.0.2-8451 Update 9) to a CentOS6 server using Rsync via SSH.

**CentOS6 server configuration**

**/etc/rsyncd.conf**

```
uid = root
gid = root
max connections = 10
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
auth users = synology
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
max verbosity = 2
transfer logging = yes

[synology1]
path = /mnt/disk/synology/
hosts allow = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (Synology server's IP)
list = true
read only = no
```

**/etc/xinetd.d/rsync**

```
service rsync
{
    disable = no
    flags           = IPv6
    socket_type     = stream
    wait            = no
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/bin/rsync
    server_args     = --daemon
    log_on_failure  += USERID
}
```

**A system user** called 'synology' also exists on my system, with a password equal to the rsync user 'synology' provided in /etc/rsyncd.secrets.

I try this from the Synology server:

```
rsync -av /tmp/try/ synology@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx::synology1 -e 'ssh -v'
```

and obtain:

> OpenSSH_6.8p1-hpn14v6, OpenSSL 1.0.2j-fips  26 Sep 2016
>   debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port xxxxx.
>   debug1: Connection established.
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>   debug1: identity file /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
>   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8p1-hpn14v6
>   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
>   debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
>   debug1: Remote is NON-HPN aware
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>   debug1: AUTH STATE IS 0
>   debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-ctr'
>   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
>   debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is 'aes128-ctr'
>   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
>   debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
>   debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
>   debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx
>   debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
>   debug1: Found key in /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
>   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>   debug1: Trying private key: /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_rsa
>   debug1: Trying private key: /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_dsa
>   debug1: Trying private key: /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
>   debug1: Trying private key: /var/services/homes/admin/.ssh/id_ed25519
>   debug1: Next authentication method: password
>   synology@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
>   debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
>   Authenticated to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:xxxxx).
>   debug1: HPN to Non-HPN Connection
>   debug1: Final hpn_buffer_size = 2097152
>   debug1: HPN Disabled: 0, HPN Buffer Size: 2097152
>   debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
>   debug1: Enabled Dynamic Window Scaling
>   debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
>   debug1: Entering interactive session.
>   debug1: Sending command: rsync --server --daemon .
>   debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
>   debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
>   debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
>   debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
>   debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
>   Transferred: sent 2872, received 2544 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
>   Bytes per second: sent 14501.0, received 12844.9
>   debug1: Exit status 1
>   rsync error: rsync service is no running (code 43) at io.c(687) [sender=3.0.9]

Ooooh, am I puzzled after various try and hours of blurry googling. Few questions for my sake!

1/ do I actually have to have the same account (user/password) on my CentOS system and on rsync configuration to be able to rsync via ssh?

2/ what's causing my "**rsync error: rsync service is no running**" here? any idea?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be trying to combine 2 slightly different uses of rsync as a daemon. Your server configuration will respond to requests on the rsync port 873, whereas your command is connecting with `-e ssh` and so running `rsync --server --daemon` over that connection instead.  If you look at the man page entry for `--config=FILE` it mentions

> The default is /etc/rsyncd.conf unless the daemon is running over a
>       remote shell program and the remote user is not the super-user; in that
>       case the default is rsyncd.conf in the current directory (typi- cally
>       $HOME)

In your case you seem to be using the user `synology`, so the rsyncd.conf file should probably be in directory `~synology/`.

Comment: Indeed I had to create a new rsyncd.conf in my synology user home, and modify it to indicate files (log, lock, etc.) present in that very folder. Well spotted !

Answer (score 1):

> 1/ do I actually have to have the same account (user/password) on my CentOS system and on rsync configuration to be able to rsync via ssh?

No, certainly not.

> 2/ what's causing my "rsync error: rsync service is no running" here? any idea?

On the server, there is no `rsync` service running on the server. You most probably miss this part (per the [this tutorial](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=rsync)):

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/xinetd start
```